# How to insert value to textboxes having same class name in jquery

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, arraylist

I have arraylist with values in sorted order and I want to insert values in text boxes(input type="text" class="same") of arraylist .

here is my javascript code

```
    $("#getdata").click(function(){

       var serial_no = [];

       <s:iterator value="cmadispatchmoreEquipmentDetailslist" status="a">

         serial_no.push(<s:property  value="serialno" />);

    </s:iterator>
          for(var m=0;m<serial_no.length;m++)
              {
             $("input.serialnocls").each(function (){

                $("input.serialnocls").val(serial_no[m]);
             });
              }


        });
```

here is the code for jsp

```
  <input type="text" class="serialnocls" name="" />
```

I have attached a screen shot here[image]

I want to set values from arraylist to serial no. please help....
final output should be
[image: Final output wanted]

but i am getting
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codes below may work for you .

```
$(function(){

    var serial_no = [];
    //init serial_no as what you want.
    for(var i=0; i<6; i++){
        serial_no.push(i+1);
    }

    //now set value into the textbox 
    $(".serialnocls").each(function(i){
        $(this).val(serial_no[i]);
    })

});
```

the key point is you should use the `i` in each(function(i){}) stand for the `index`.
here is the jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/0woctcmt/

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick

```
$("input.serialnocls").each(function (){

    $(this).val(serial_no[m]);
});
```

Comment: m is initialized inside for loop

Comment: The final output of the method would be that all the text fields will be set with the last element's value. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you provide the final Javascript that is emitted to the page? If possible try debugging that

Answer (score 0):

```
var m=0;
$("input.serialnocls").each(function (){
      if(m < serial_no.length){
          $("input.serialnocls").val(serial_no[m++]);           
       }
});
```

Comment: same result as above...no success

Comment: Are you sure `serial_no` contains multiple value ? Can you show value of `serial_no`?